# Same script work well at the jenkins script console, but not at the pipline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins 2.161

I have a script, which calculate number of active executors.
This script work well at the Jenkins console (https://url/jenkins/script), but throw the exception when it placed inside pipeline. I don't know what to fix, because all println show right values.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    runningBuilds = Jenkins.instance.getView('All').getBuilds().findAll() { it.getResult().equals(null) }
                    println("runung builds:"+runningBuilds)
                    a = runningBuilds.findIndexValues { name -> name =~ /(t)/ } 
                    println("just a= "+a)
                    size = a.size()
                    println ("size= "+size)
                    println ("end")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output from /script webpage:

```
runung builds:[tst/cleanup_2 #2, tests/m-t1/isfile #9]
just a= [0, 1]
size= 2
end
```

Console output:

````
runung builds:[tests/t1 #113, tst/cleanup_2 #2, tests/m-t1/isfile #9]
[Pipeline] echo
just a= [0, 1, 2]
[Pipeline] echo
size= 3
[Pipeline] echo
end
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
an exception which occurred:
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.withscript.WithScriptScript.script
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.LabelScript@1fb162b9
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@1403f46c
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@3471f27b
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@3cd6fde8
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@3cd6fde8
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:569)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(LinkedHashMap.java:333)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor186.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:273)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.SerializableScript.writeObject(SerializableScript.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor201.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:273)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor186.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:273)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$0(RiverWriter.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:121)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:482)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:458)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:445)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:372)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE```
````

Answer (score 4):

Jenkins Pipeline executes Groovy code using [Groovy CPS](https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps) and it has some limitations compared to a plain Groovy language. Operations like `findAll()` or `findIndexValues()` does not serialize, thus they have to be executed in a non-CPS manner to take effect.

> In order to provide *durability*, which means that running Pipelines can survive a restart of the Jenkins master, Scripted Pipeline must serialize data back to the master. Due to this design requirement, some Groovy idioms such as `collection.each { item → /* perform operation */ }` are not fully supported. See [JENKINS-27421](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27421) and [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481) for more information.
>
> *Source: [https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#differences-from-plain-groovy](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#differences-from-plain-groovy_)*

According to the [official Jenkins best practices guideline](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/01/pipeline-scalability-best-practice/), you should extract the operations like `findAll()` and `findIndexValues()` to separate methods annotated with `@NonCPS` to avoid running pipeline steps inside non-CPS method. If you do so, you will get unpredictable results instead. Consider the following example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    runningBuilds = findBuilds()
                    println("runung builds:"+runningBuilds)
                    a = findIndexValues(runningBuilds)
                    println("just a= "+a)
                    size = a.size()
                    println ("size= "+size)
                    println ("end")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@NonCPS
def findBuilds() {
    return Jenkins.instance.getView('All').getBuilds().findAll() { it.getResult().equals(null) }
}

@NonCPS
def findIndexValues(builds) {
    return builds.findIndexValues { name -> name =~ /(t)/ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the issue with non-serializable types (see [this](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/01/pipeline-scalability-best-practice/) for details).

Try to use this syntax with `@NonCPS` annotation:

```
@NonCPS
def print_details() {
    runningBuilds = Jenkins.instance.getView('All').getBuilds().findAll() { it.getResult().equals(null) }
    println("running builds:"+runningBuilds)
    a = runningBuilds.findIndexValues { name -> name =~ /(t)/ } 
    println("just a= "+a)
    size = a.size()
    println ("size= "+size)
    println ("end")
}

print_details()
```